# Where do i change password authentication min rule in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

Here is the error, i need it to be min:4 characters not 6 and i can't find the file to change it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGII0.png

Comment: Can you post code and not image, and show what you try, but you can found it in `Auth/RegisterController.php`

Answer (score 1):

You can found the function `validator` in `Auth/RegisterController.php`

```
/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
```

You need to change the validator rules.

Take time to look this [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#manually-creating-validators)

Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

This is not authentication but registration which the panel title already says, and the validation is in an obvious place called `RegisterController`. So take a look at the `validator` function and you will find the gift :)